# Emulator для Андроид

Tags: android, android-studio, эмулятор

Посоветуйте какой нибудь Emulator, а то когда я запускаю эмулятор Android studio, компьютер начинает сильно тормозить.

Существует ли какой нибудь легкий эмулятор, чтобы не тормозил компьютер и быстро работал с vs кодом.

Comment: Используйте реальное устройство. А вообще есть ещё Genymotion. Но я им никогда не пользовался, не уверен что он сильно решит вашу проблему

Comment: соглашусь с @СергейБувака genymotion полегче чем эмулятор AS, поэтому берите его либо реальное устройство.

Comment: Тормозит скорее всего из за того, что не подключена аппаратная виртуализация, стоковый эмулятор AS поддерживает не все процессоры для корректной работы, поэтому неплохо бы добавить конфигурацию вашего ПК в вопрос.

Comment: @СергейБувака genymotion денег стоит, разве нет?

Comment: Я же написал что им не пользовался. Я вы не хотите платить то пользуйтесь бесплатной студией. Реальными устройством. За комфортн надо платить

Comment: @Эникейщик там есть и бесплатные эмуляторы, только регистрироваться надо (по крайней мере так было несколько лет назад, когда я им последний раз пользовался, может сейчас и все платное уже)

Comment: @Эникейщик, бесплатный если вы зарегистрированы у них в системе :)

Comment: Спасибо всем, попробую с genymotion , надеюсь поможет.